# Using fetch() without Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

Smarty 3 has an option to set (assign) a variable and then include (fetch) a file to a new variable.
How can I do this without the Smarty class? `file_get_contents` would not work, is there something else?

For example, this is the Smarty code:

```
<?php
$variable = 'Hello World';
$smarty->assign('variable', $variable);
$content = $smarty->fetch('content.tpl'); // content.tpl have "{$variable}" inside
echo '<script>document.write("' . $content . '")</script>'; // this will output <script>document.write("Hello World")</script>
?>
```

I want to do it without Smarty:

```
<?php
$variable = 'Hello World';
$content = file_get_contents('content.php'); // content.php have "echo $variable;" inside
echo '<script>document.write("' . $content . '")</script>';// this needs to output <script>document.write("Hello World")</script>, but it's outputing echo $variable;
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to just assign variables, or use modifiers too?

Comment: Just to assign variables - the output file will echo them. For example $var = 'hi'; $output = open('output.php'); echo &output; // Needs to return 'hi'

Comment: And what will be in output.php? It will be smarty template or what?

Comment: It was Smarty template, I replaced the functions to PHP only. Basically, I'm removing the Smarty.

Comment: I don't get what do you need. Can't you just use include('output.php')?

Comment: Well, the output.php needs to be set to a variable, because after that it will be included in a javascript, something like <script>document.write('<php echo $output; ?>');</script>

Comment: I still don't get this... Please edit your post and provide example of output.php and example usage.

Comment: Isn't it kind of silly to do that? Just echo '<script>document.write("' . $variable . '")</script>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of buffering tricks.

```
function fetch($filename, array $vars) {

   ob_start(); // Start output buffering

   extract($vars); // Extract variables

   require($filename); // Include a file

   return ob_get_clean(); // Pass variables to included filename and return output as a string
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
$content = fetch('content.php', array(
  'variable' => 'Hello World',
  'name'     => 'John Doe',
 ));

echo $content;
```

My `content.php` looks like as follows:

```
<div>
  <b><?php echo $variable; ?></b>, you're logged in as <?php echo $name; ?>
</div>
```

It outputs Hello World, you're logged in as John Doe

Comment: Looks very good, but it doesn't echo anything. Does I need any PHP settings for the buffering tricks?

Comment: put `error_reporting(-1)` at the top of your script. This will ensure that all errors are shown

Comment: Notice:  Undefined variable: variable in content.php

Comment: I did it this way: <?php $variable = 'Hello World'; ob_start(); include "content.php"; $content = ob_get_clean(); echo $content; ?>. BTW, is the best way to do it? Hopefully, thousands of people are going to access this script. I'm asking about the server overloading and stuff.

Comment: `ob_get_clean()` essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean(). (see the php.net/ob_get_clean)